# Как правильно создать роуты для роутера в паттерне MVC?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть данные маршруты для класса `Router`:

```
$routes = array(
    'product/([0-9]+)' => 'product/view/$1',
    'category/([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)' => 'catalog/category/$1/$2',
    'category/([0-9]+)' => 'catalog/category/$1',
    'admin' => 'admin/index',
    'contacts' => 'site/contact',
    'about' => 'site/about',
);
```

т.е. ссылка `site/product/45` будет вести на товар с ID 45, ссылка `site/category/2`
будет вести на категорию с ID 2. Я хочу достичь того, чтобы продукты открывались по ссылке: `site/category1/category2/category3/product-name`, где `category1/category2/category3` - это названия категорий, а не их ID. Категорий может быть несколько, т.е. это подкатегории. Каким образом я могу это сделать через данные routes?

Comment: у вас сейчас там `/category/id` и `product/id`, а вы приводите пример `category1/cateogry2/product-name`. В примере вашем нет вообще id никаких, приведите нормальный реальный пример желаемой ссылки. _зы: имеет значение только последняя категория, поэтому первые можно просто в `.*?` пропустить_

Comment: @teran отредактировал вопрос

Comment: `.*/([\w-]+?)/([\w-]+)` какой  нибудь не пойдет?

Comment: ... и роут от teran прописывать последним в списке.

Comment: @teran не до конца понял, что он обозначает, можете объяснить подробнее? В regex не силен :(

Comment: дак `[\w-]`  соответствует всем буквам-цифрам и тире. так что две таких группы в конце будут соответствовать последней категории и названию продукта. а все что до этого попадет в `.*`

Comment: [Ваш сегодняшний вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739516/) - продолжение этого? Т.е. вам нужно `'product/view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)' => 'product/view/$1/$2'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, но немного по-другому. Роут, который Вы написали выше, позволит пользователям переходить только по ссылке `https://site.com/product/view/$categorylink/$productlink`. На самом деле, мне нужен был роут `([^/]+)/([^/]+)' => 'product/view/$1/$2'. Вопрос создал вследствие того, что изменились условия и мне нужно было именно регулярное выражение. Конечно, хотелось бы добавить возможность подкатегорий, но боюсь, что будет сложно (хотя зря, но нужно быстрее разработать бизнес-логику, это можно оставить на будущее)

Comment: Дело в том, что у вас есть только столько `$n`, сколько `(...)` у вас в регулярке. Нельзя использовать `(?:([^/]+)/([^/]+))+` и рассчитывать на бесконечное кол-во пар категорий-ИД.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Часть пути между / в ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739516/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5)