# Часть пути между / в ссылке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка в роутах:

```
'product/([0-9]+)' => 'product/view/$1'
```

Что вызывает функцию view в контроллере ProductController.
Мне нужно сделать следующий роут:

```
'(*regex*)/(*regex*)' => 'product/view/$1/$2'
```

Где `*regex*` - это regEx, допускающее следующие символы: `0-9 aA-zZ - _`,
т.е. любые символы, которые возможны в адресной строке, кроме `/`.

Как правильно составить данное выражение?

Comment: `[^/]+` подойдёт?

Comment: @vp_arth да, спасибо) сделайте ответ, пожалуйста, чтобы другие видели, если таким же вопросом зададутся)

Comment: Посмотрите на заголовок вопроса и на список "Похожие" справа. Как в этом можно что-то найти? Нужно либо переоформлять вопрос, либо он бесполезен. В любом случае, Вы можете добавить ответ сами ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение "*Всё кроме /*" выглядит так: `[^/]+`.

В Вашем случае:

```
'([^/]+)/([^/]+)' => 'product/view/$1/$2'
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл ответ добавить сам) Правильно понимаю, что `[^/+]+` будет исключать / и +?

Comment: Да, правильно. Некоторые символы (вроде "-") придётся экранировать.